# Configured the log4j2. log file is not getting created?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Recently i have moved from log4j1.x to 2.x every thing has changed i cant figure out now how to log.

i have configured the properties but the file is not getting created. any help, Thanks in advance

if needed i will post my old configuration. any idea on where i did wrong

Log4jTest.java

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder;


public class Log4jTest {
    public static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log4jTest.class);
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
          File loggerFile = new File("C:\\Users\\207596\\TestRuns\\src\\Samples\\log4j2.properties");
          try {
            InputStream logInputStream = new FileInputStream(loggerFile);
            props.load(logInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
          LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
          Configuration config = new PropertiesConfigurationBuilder()
                      .setConfigurationSource(ConfigurationSource.NULL_SOURCE)
                      .setRootProperties(props)
                      .setLoggerContext(context)
                      .build();
           context.setConfiguration(config);
           Configurator.initialize(config);
           
           logger.info("file has been configured");
    }

}
```

log4j2.properties

```
status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename =C:\Users\207596\Desktop\Test.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = info

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = info

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = C:\Users\207596\Desktop\test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy:dd:MM hh:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=2MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = com.Log4jTest
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
 
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: I'm not too certain if your configuration loading is correct and causing the problem. Log4j 2 will scan the classpath for any properties file and load them, so why not place it like that? https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-properties-example/

Comment: hey @Fullslack i am getting the console output but not getting the test.log file output

Comment: Log4j 2 will revert to default values if no properties file can be found. Seeing the console output is no guarantee that the settings file is loaded. Please try the most basic settings: placing it in the classpath.

Comment: configured it still not working